# SSRS - How to create a sum (total) of an expression column?

Tags: reporting-services, sum, expression

After plenty of research, it seemd I can't find a well-explained solution to my problem. I'll join some screenshots of my Tablix, group rows, and group columns to help you to understand.

First of all, here's my tablix. It's linked to a SharePoint List.

[image]

The expressions are all like this :

```
=Count(Fields!ID.Value, "NameOfTheGroup")
```

It counts the number of elements that are filtered by one of the group chosen in the expression, and it works perfectly fine at this point.

Now, here's my groups :

[image]

They all contains filters tomanage the count precisely to the need.

**What I want to do :** In the last row, I want to display the sum of each column that is in a group row. But theses rows aren't datasets fields, they are just only expressions, and I can't find a way to create a proper total of each column. I heard of Running Value but the few solutions I found about it didn't work.

Thanks for the future help.

**EDIT:** Actually, the problem seems to be much more complex: any rows I create under my group rows are invisible : if I create a new row under the "Classification", outside the "Classification" row group, the expression I insert in the "CDI", "CDD", etc... columns stay blank. I tried with various expression or just values like "Hello World".

Comment: Have you tried simply summing your expression? `=Sum(Count(Fields!ID.Value, "NameOfTheGroup"))`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer !
Sadly, I've already tried and this doesn't display anything : the field stay blank. Actually, all of the function like "Count()", etc... The result stays blank. Maybe, Is it because of the groups?

Comment: I would try altering your expression to : =Count(Fields!ID.Value)

Comment: The result stay sadly blank. Don't know why any result doesn't even show in the preview.